# How to create a portfolio website for minimal cost?

Tags: web-hosting, website-design, domain-registration, looking-for-hosting

I am planning on creating an online portfolio for myself, to use in my resume and to use for other personal use, with my own domain name. I am pretty sure there is nothing free out there to create a domain name and have a website for ourselves (correct me if I am wrong.)

So I looked up Godaddy.com and found some domains really cheap, like for $4.99 a year which looked so unbelievable. I need your suggestions on how to get started on this. I plan to design my website on my own and post photos and make modifications to the code since i am a web developer. Which website would be good to have things the way I want them to be and what would be the price.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by "which website would be good to have things the way i want them to be", but if you're trying to ask about web hosts, I would encourage you to use a more above board web host, like DreamHost. You will get better customer service and not contribute to the skeezy practice of domain squatting/speculating.

As WalterJ89 mentioned, most web hosts give you at least a year's free registration on your first domain, but decent ones give you free registration for the life of your account, and the price difference between domain registrars is usually negligible for .com/.net/.org and other major TLDs.

Some things you will also get with DreamHost that you won't with GoDaddy (not for the same price at least) include:

- unlimited shell accounts (full unix shell)
- unlimited SFTP accounts + anonymous ftp
- unlimited e-mail accounts
- unlimited MySQL databases
- unlimited storage + 50GB backups
- SVN/CVS repository

But the most important feature you get is a hosting company that's passionate about what they do, is run by very competent employees (with a great sense of humor, which really comes through in their regular newsletters), and who have a strong sense of ethics. DreamHost is also constantly improving their hosting plans, and existing customers are always given automatic upgrades/price reductions so you're rewarded for your loyalty rather than punished for it as is the case with many web hosts.

As I said earlier, DreamHost has *great* customer support, and in my experience they have always gone above and beyond what is required of them, which explains their popularity and success. They don't have huge call centers to handle 24/7 phone support from all customers, but what they lack in quantity, they make up for in quality, as their customer support staff are probably more knowledgeable than 99% of the IT tech support staff out there. And even without free phone support, all inquiries are answered within 24 hours (usually less), and I've never had any technical questions/problems that they weren't able to resolve within 1 or 2 emails.

Just about the only thing you can't count on DH customer support to help you with are custom-compiled PHP binaries, which very few shared hosting users would ever encounter (especially as most shared hosts don't let you use your own self-compiled PHP binary).

Comment: Dreamhost is awesome, they give you so much flexibility that you wouldn't get with many other shared hosts. Nice extras are the rewards program and the knowledge base.

Comment: Yea, I personally don't take advantage of the reward program as aggressively as I should since I'm always referring people to them just on principle that they are such a good value/web host, but I know a lot of people who save a lot of money through their rewards program. And the KB is also a good point. Unsupported topics, like self-compiling PHP, is covered in the KB so you get community support even where official support is unavailable.

Comment: Wait a second. Dreamhost COMES with an SVN repository? I've been pulling my hair out trying to get SVN installed on Bluehost and so has everyone else who uses Bluehost.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be fine on Godaddy.  Most good web hosts actually include a domain name with the hosting account.

Something like WordPress would probably be the easiest to use as a content management system.  I believe Godaddy has the option to install this in the control panel.

Personally I use HostMonster, mostly for the great support.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, price for `.com`, `.net`, .`org`, and `.info` domains fall in 8-10$ range. I prefer Godaddy for the purchasing for a fair deal.

If you are just planning to just to host your portfolio, then you may use deviantart.com, but it depends on what sort of profile you want. If you are planning some independent platform, then WordPress will be better for you. It'll not only give you free hosting but a dashboard, inbuilt themes and a lot of other goodies.

Don't waste your money for hosting.